# How to print strings from a text file,separated by new line in Python

Tags: python

I'm new in Python and i'm challenging myself by making an online library management with prompt for the 1st phase.I'm stacked in search function.I have found how to print a user's input,but i can't find how to print and the following data.I want to search a book by name.If book's name is in the text,i want to print the details of the book,like author,isbn etc.

Here is the following code i have made:

```
 def search():
    search_book = input('Search a book: ')

    with open('library.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        index = 0
        for line in f:
            index += 1
            if search_book in line:
                print(f'{search_book} is in line {index}')
                for details in range(index,index+5):
                    print(line[details])
```

And this is the text file's data:

```
FIRST
ME 
9781234
2000
Science

SECOND
YOU
9791234
1980
Literature
```

It is separated by new line.As example a user input the name FIRST and the result will be:

```
FIRST
ME 
9781234
2000
Science
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You can use `lines = f.readlines()` instead and then use an index into that array. Like: `for line_number in range(0, len(lines, 5):....`

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is working and what is not working?  I didn't try out your code, but I think you last line should be print(f.readline()).  Not 100% sure though.  You might also consider using a json file instead of a text file.

Answer (score 1):

There are two file options we can consider,

1. Csv file - Instead of individual readline, you could use one line for one book entry.

```
   # ---------test.csv -------------
   # BookName, ItemCode, Price 
   # Book1, 00012, 14.55
   # Book2, 00232, 55.12
   # -----End Csv-------------------
   import csv 
   def read_csv(filename:str):
      file_contents = None
      # reading csv file 
      with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile: 
         file_contents = csv.reader(csvfile)
      return file_contents
    
    def search(file_contents, book_name:str):
       if not file_contents:
         return None
       for line in file_contents:
         if book_name in line: 
            return line
    
     if __name__ == '__main__':
       file_contents = read_csv('test.csv')
       line = search(file_contents, 'ME')
       print(line if line else 'No Hit Found')
```

2. Json - This is much better option than csv file

```
import json
def read_json(filename:str) -> dict:
   with open(filename) as json_file:
      all_books = json.load(json_file)
   return all_books

 def search(all_books:dict, book_name:str):
   for book_id, book_details in all_books.items():
      if book_details['Name'] == book_name:
         return book_details
   return None
 
 if __name__ == '__main__':
    all_books = read_json('books.json')
    book = search(all_books, 'YOU')
    print(book if book else 'Not hit found')
```

If your file contents can't change, then I will go with @tripleee suggestion above. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a line at a time, and looping over the first *line's* contents. At this point in the program, there are not yet any additional lines. But a fix is relatively easy:

```py
def search():
    search_book = input('Search a book: ')

    with open('library.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
        index = 0
        print_this_many = 0
        for line in f:
            index += 1
            if search_book in line:
                print(f'{search_book} is in line {index}')
                print_this_many = 5
            if print_this_many:
                print(line, end='')
                print_this_many -= 1
```

We don't have the next lines in memory yet, but we can remember how many of them to print as we go ahead and read more of them. The `print_this_many` variable is used for this: When we see the title we want, we set it to 5 (to specify that this and the next four lines should be printed). Now, each time we read a new line, we check if this variable is positive; if it is, we print the line and decrement the variable. When it reaches zero, we will no longer print the following lines. This allows us to "remember" across iterations of the `for` loop which reads each new line whether we are in the middle of printing something.

A much better solution is to read the database into memory once, and organize the lines into a dictionary, for example.

```py
def read_lib(filename):
    library = dict()
    with open(filename) as lib:
        title = None
        info = []
        for line in lib:
            line = line.rstrip('\n')
            if title is None:
                title = line
            elif line == '':
                if title and info:
                    library[title] = info
                title = None
            else:
                info.append(line)


def search(title, library):
    if title in library:
        return library[title]
    else:
        return None

def main():
    my_library = read_lib('library.txt')
    while True:
        sought = input('Search a book: ')
        found = search(sought, my_library)
        if found:
            print('\n'.join(found))
        else:
            print('Sorry, no such title in library')
```

Comment: It works!.I would appreciate if you explain the ideology of print_this_many variable

Comment: Isn't it obvious? I added a brief explanation.